# How to communicate to a SQL Server database using cellular data services from a SIM5215E chip?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cellular-network, pic32

I am working on a project where I am trying to use cellular data services on the 3G WCDMA network in order to send data to a SQL Server database. On the client side, I am using a SIM5215E chip to connect the cellular network. This chip is being controlled by sending AT commands over a UART connection from a PIC32MX675F512H microcontroller. I was wondering, is there a relatively simple way to have this data be accepted by a SQL Server database? I have found many services and references online for sending SMS to a SQL Server database using a SMS gateway but I haven't been able to find anything for cellular data to the database.

Comment: You should be splitting this into two problems.  First is the communications problem -- getting data from the client to the server via the CDMA network.  Second is the database piece, once it's received on the server it's just data and becomes a standard database problem.

Comment: Hmm, I guess my question would be more on the getting the data to server itself. Is there a way to perform the handshaking required (entering username and password for the server) with only sending data to the server? For SQL servers I believe there is a more complex handshaking process that requires the client to have some drivers or an operating system to support these drivers. I am only working with a PIC32.